# Add resources or property to Websphere's classpath

Tags: properties, websphere, rad, ear, application.xml

I've a problem and a solution. But I don't like my solution, could someone provide an elegant way of solving this?

This is for running web application inside IDE. I've an EAR project and I'm using RAD7.5. My EAR project looks like

EAR_Project 
   Deployment Descriptor 
       Module 
        Jar1 
        Jar2 
        War 
    Meta-Inf 
       application.xml

My question is, Jar1 and Jar2 has its own libraries and properties files. As of now, I copy all libraries and properties of Jar1&Jar2 into War/Web-Inf and it works fine. Is there a config change that i make to application.xml so that I don't have to copy dependent libraries and properties? Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application.xml there can be `<library-directory>` element that points to the location to shared libraries within EAR. For example, for directory `lib` in the root of EAR there should be entry `<library-directory>lib</library-directory>` in application.xml:

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">

  <module>
    <java>module1.jar</java>
  </module>

  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>module2.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>module2</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>

  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>

</application>
```

Comment: could you post a complete example of this?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Added complete application.xml